# Salvar valor em SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Como eu faço para salvar e recuperar informações em um arquivo Prefence do Android.

Exemplo

```
String  a = "stack overflow"
int     b = 32;
boolean c = true;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Observe os comentários no código, que explicam o que cada linha faz.

Para salvar em SharedPreferences:

```java
// recupera (ou cria) uma instância editável do arquivo de preferencia do Android, 
// pelo seu nome/chave (no caso "pref")
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

// seta uma propriedade do tipo 'String', com a chave 'a' e com um valor string
editor.putString("a", "stack overflow");

// seta uma propriedade do tipo 'int', com a chave 'b' e com um valor inteiro
editor.putInt("b", 32);

// seta uma propriedade do tipo 'boolean', com a chave 'c' e com um valor boolean
editor.putBoolean("c", true);

// aplica/salva as alterações nas preferencias 
editor.commit();
```

Para recuperar os valores de SharedPreferences:

```java
// recupera (ou cria) uma instância do arquivo de preferencia do Android, 
// pelo seu nome/chave (no caso "pref")
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);

// recupera a propriedade com a chave 'a' e do tipo 'String',
// passando um valor default como segundo parâmetro,
// no caso de não encontrar um propriedade com essa chave para recuperar 
String a = pref.getString("a", null);

// recupera a propriedade com a chave 'b' e do tipo 'int',
// passando um valor default como segundo parâmetro,
// no caso de não encontrar um propriedade com essa chave para recuperar
int b = pref.getInt("b", 0);

// recupera a propriedade com a chave 'c' e do tipo 'boolean',
// passando um valor default como segundo parâmetro, no caso de não encontrar um
// propriedade com essa chave para recuperar
boolean c = pref.getBoolean("c", true);
```

Para mais detalhes consulte a [documentação de SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) e/ou [como utilizar SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).