# Como criar uma variável que armazene um valor mesmo que reinicie aplicação ou mudar de cena no Android?

Tags: java, android

Como criar uma variável que armazena um valor valor mesmo que reinicie ou mudar de cena aplicação,não sei seria um banco de dados ou se existe algo simples

Comment: Veja na documentação [SharedPrefereces](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) e/ou esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25168/2541)

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo de utilização do `SharedPreferences`:

```
/**
 * Classe encapsula as funcionalidades de leitura e gravação no SharedPreferences
 */
public class SharedPreferencesController {
    /**
     * Constantes utilizadas para salvar / resgatar os dados
     */
    private String DADOS = "DADOS";
    private String CAMPO = "CAMPO";

    /**
     * Grava as informações do objeto em um SharedPreferences.
     */
    public void salvar(final String  campo, final Context mContext){
        if(null == campo) return;
        //Cria uma instancia do SharedPreferences
       SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(DADOS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Criamos um instancia do editor, para salvamos os dados
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(CAMPO, campo);
        // Para que as informações sejam atualizadas
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Coleta as informações do objeto em um SharedPreferences.
     */
    public String ler(final Context mContext){
        if(null == mContext) return null;
        //Cria uma instancia do SharedPreferences
        final SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(DADOS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // se for nulo, n˜ao temos mais o que fazer, e retornamos nulo!
        if(null == prefs) return null;

        /**
         * Coleta os valores!
         *  Para carregar um valor passamos o nome da Propriedade e um valor padrão.
         *  Se não haver dados para esta propriedade, ele irá retornar o valor padão
         */
        final String  campo  = prefs.getString(CAMPO, null);
        return campo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pouco aconselhável esta forma de validar parâmetros: `if(null == campo) return;` e `if(null == mContext) return null;`

Comment: @ramaral poderia me explicar o porquê?  Penso assim : Se o contexto é  nulo,não  podemos  criar a instância, então não  temos mais o q fazer. Já no campo seria aceitável, caso queira limpar o valor! Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Se o cliente desses métodos passou valores nulos então ele tem um erro no programa. Ao serem tratados dessa maneira ele não é notificado disso.