# Como pegar um item de uma lista e mover com dedo para outra posição no Android?

Tags: java, android, listview

Eu tenho uma lista e gostaria de mover o primeiro item dela para a última posição arrastando com o dedo, alguém poderia dar alguma sugestão de como fazer isso no Android?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Salvar valor em SharedPreference](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25167/salvar-valor-em-sharedpreference)

Comment: [Aqui](https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo) tem um exemplo.. Só implementar os arquivos lá no `helper` na sua aplicação e algumas coisas no `adapter`.. mas é tranquilo. Se tiver alguma dúvida só perguntar

Comment: Valeu Marcos, deu certo! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo.. Só implementar os arquivos lá no helper na sua aplicação e algumas coisas no adapter.. mas é tranquilo. Se tiver alguma dúvida só perguntar

Comment: Que exemplo? Você não adicionou nenhum link ou codigo, essa resposta da forma como está não faz sentido algum.

Comment: Eu quis citar o comentário do Marco Giovanni, mas parece que não foi direito :/

Comment: Quando for assim, só pedir pro usuario responder, ao inves de replicar. :)

Comment: Beleza, e agora? O que eu faço?